# Pig calculating avg of delay fails

Tags: apache-pig, average

I have a file for airplanes data, having airplane dest and delay(delay can be negative or positve number)

```
A = load ‘flightdelays’ using Pigstorage(‘,’);
B = foreach a generate $14 as delay:int, $17 as dest:chararray;
C = group b all; -- this is failing for cast error, also get an error failed to read data from input file..
D =foreach c generate b.dest, AVG(b.delay);
```

When i execute this , i get 0 records read from source file and mapreduce job failed..

Why is it not able to calculate AVG?

Answer (score 0):

Check the extension/path of the file.Is your file comma separated? Also,there are plenty of case issues with your script.

- PigStorage - s is small in your load statement.

  A = load ‘flightdelays’ using PigStorage(‘,’);
- B = foreach a generate $14 as delay:int, $17 as dest:chararray;

There is no relation called a,b,c.You are loading data to relation A and so on.

Comment: Input file is a .csv file loaded in hdfs directory
When i load the file , its getting stored in relation "A" correctly
In relation B , i am able to filter two columns and data looks like
(SFO, -5)
(SFO,10)
(SFO, 2)
(SFO,-10)
(DEN,10)
(DEN,11)
In relation C when i try to group it by dest, command runs fine but when i dump C, it says no relevant data found, but i can do group all..

Answer (score 0):

1st thing ***A,a treated differently***(in pig relation names are case sensitive) and 2nd thing while calculating Aggregate function on relation and group by on any attribute..

In FOREACH you should specify ***grouping attribute and aggregate function***..

In this scenario you used group by all so you can't use b.dest along with aggregate function..

If you want destination wise AVG() delay then you should group by dest..

Comment: Hi Ankur, will the code below work a = load '/user/horton/flightdelays' using PigStorage(',');
b = foreach a generate $14 as arrdelay:int, $17 as dest:chararray;
c = group b by dest;
d = foreach c generate b.dest, AVG(b.arrdelay);
e = store d into '/user/horton/average' ;-- the input file is a .csv file and when i load data into d -its doesnt error out, but when i dump d it says no relation for d